# Configure a windows program to automatically relaunch if closed?

Tags: windows-7, process

I am an IT administrator. I have a user that uses a digital dictation device. The device requires that the docking software always be running in the background. However, I can't stop the user from accidentally closing the program.

Is there a way in windows I can configure the program to automatically relaunch if it is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to write a service that periodically checked that the docking software process was still running and if it wasn't started it again.

Doing it as service would mean that the user would be less likely to stop that.

Comment: I'm interested in this idea, but i'm not sure how to write a service like that.

Comment: @user53639 - search on Stack Overflow. I'm sure the question has come up there before. The simplest way might be to type your question title "How do I write a service to automatically restart a program" and check the list of questions it suggests. If non answer your question ask your own.

Comment: Older versions of Windows had optional utilities (`Instrsrv.exe` and `Srvany.exe`) in their Resource Kits that allowed you to [run user applications as sevices](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890). Even if there are no Win 7 equivalents, you might still be able to get and use the older versions if you can find them -- search for the "Windows NT Resource Kit".